# Too High Computer Conditions?

Tags: windows-7, temperature

CPU
    Intel Core i3 2330M @ 2.20GHz   73 °C
    Sandy Bridge 32nm Technology

Storage
    931GB Western Digital WDC WD10JPVX-22JC3T0 (SATA)   45 °C

Should I be worried about this?  Nothing is running on my computer Except VLC playing an .mp4 file.  Are these temps to high?

Toshiba Satellite
6 GB Of Ram

Comment: The way Toshiba does their cooling systems, any temperature is too high :P

Comment: @digitxp - LOL - well it's only been about the past 2 weeks I have noticed these higher temps.  I have already opened it up and blown out all the dust but no avail.

Comment: http://ark.intel.com/products/53434/Intel-Core-i3-2330M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_20-GHz :  TJUNCTION  85C (PGA); 100C (BGA)

Comment: @MaQleod - what specific information am I looking for on that page that tells me if this is A-ok or failing grades?

Comment: The Tjunction values I posted, the link was just for source reference. Per Intel, "Tjunction Max is the maximum temperature the cores can reach before thermal throttling is activated. Thermal throttling happens when the processor exceeds the maximum temperature."  So as long as that processor stays under 85C, you won't have any temperature throttling issues with it.

Comment: I also looked up the spec sheet for that drive (found here: http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/SpecSheet/ENG/2879-771437.pdf) and the operating temperature for it is 0 to 60C